# How does Twitter's addition of photos to profile work when retweeting

Tags: twitter

Sometimes when I retweet a post with a photo (the ones that are shown in the feed), the photo is added to my photos and videos on the profile and sometimes it doesn't. How does it work?

Comment: You have any examples?

Comment: I do but that's on my named account... Basically sometimes I retweet and the photo in the post will be added to my profile and sometimes it will not! I am just baffled by this.